# cp210x and modbus mutiple masters in C#

Tags: .net, serial-port, modbus

I'm connecting to multiple devices via Silicon CP210x USB to RS485 driver. Each device receives a (virtual) COM assigned to it once plugged via a USB splitter into the computer USB port.

Therefor we have a number of devices (each on its own COM) that we have to connect via Modbus.
Since they each have a distinct COM they all should be Modbus Master. So for each of them I've created a Modbus Master object associated to the specific port. The application is written in C# and uses System.IO.Ports.

The process of reading data from the devices is serialized (so each serial port is interrogated separately) e.g. first COM3, then COM5, ..., but the Serial Port is kept open.

The behavior is strange, sometimes it's working with multiple ports than - sometimes - suddenly one/more/all of the communication crashes and doesn't work anymore (disconnect/reconnect does not solve it), sometimes it simply doesn't connect at all, even if the COM port is present in Device Manager.

So, my questions are:

1. Should I Open Port-> Modbus Request => Close Port on each request? Would that correct this behavior?
2. Is there a "smart splitter" that can associate the virtual COM with a specific USB plug entry and ensure that the signals are never "scrambled" understanding, somehow, Silicon CP210x USB driver?

Comment: What is the *device* in question? Could you provide a link to its manual? If the devices are Modbus masters, you can not query them. If they are slaves, then you can give your PC a master role. In that case, if you're able to assign them addresses, it makes a lot more sense to connect them to the same RS485 line/bus and use single USB - RS485 converter.

Answer (score 0):

With Modbus RTU (serial) you always have to wait for the slave to respond before sending another request.

In no case can requests be sent without waiting for responses.

In a Serial communication there is no intrinsic system to avoid collisions like an ethernet network has, it has to be your software that synchronizes maintaining a strict Request-> Response order ... and it is not necessary to open and close the port every time.

And since you use RS485, why do you use so many serial ports?
The slaves could be in a single RS485 network and in the PC there could be only one physical or virtual serial port.